# What is the non-deprecated way to initialise a char * in C++?

Tags: c++

When I initialise a local `char *` variable like so in C++:

```
char * pattern = "oggS";
```

the compiler warns me:

```
Foo.cpp:34: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

What is the non-deprecated way to do this in C++?

In case it matters, here's how I'm invoking the compiler (from [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/)):

```
g++-4.5 -O0 -g3 -Wall -std=c++0x -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Foo.d" -MT"Foo.d" -o"Foo.o" "Foo.cpp"
```

Comment: +1 for reading your compiler warnings.

Comment: Note this warning is not issued in MSVC++, but maybe it should be!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want:

```
const char * pattern = "oggS";
```

Or if you intend to change the characters in the string later:

```
char pattern[] = "oggS";
```

The first one creates a pointer-to-const-char which points to a string literal. You can't change the literal through this pointer, which is good because changing literals gives you undefined behaviour. The second creates an array of 5 chars and initialises it with "oggS". The result is not a string literal, just an ordinary array, so you can change the characters it contains.

Comment: Wow, my C is obviously quite rusty! Assuming that you're Swedish, tack så mycket! ;)

Comment: Also: Consider using `std::string`.

Comment: @bobobobo: That comment is not very constructive. If you have any valid reasons for not using `std::string`, then please state them.

Comment: It just represents the position of some C++ programmers that insist on using `char*` strings, without any reasoning really